# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException while trying to access element in the list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, classcastexception

Sample Code:

```
public class A
{
    List<WebElement> itemList = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    public List<WebElement> getItemsList()
    {
        itemList = (driver.findElements(By.xpath("<some valid xpath>")));
        return(itemList);
    }
}

public class B
{
    A hp = new A();
    public void subscribe()
    {   
        hp.getItemsList().get(0).click();
    }
}
```

I am creating the list of webelements on the page in the class A and in the Class B I am trying to click on the first element.

On execution I am getting below exception:

```
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.StackOverflowError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception
```

Issues has to do some thing with findElements because when I added the elements using findElement method to the list manually in the code, code is working  fine.

In the below example I have commented the findElements line and instead added the elements manually, this code is working fine.

```
public class A
{
    List<WebElement> itemList = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

    public List<WebElement> getItemsList()
    {
        //itemList = (driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hc6|stocks|item1']/span[2]"")));
        itemList.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hc6|stocks|item1']/span[2]")));
        itemList.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hc6|stocks|item2']/span[2]")));
        itemList.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hc6|stocks|item3']/span[2]")));
        return(itemList);
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggests whats going wrong?

Comment: The error is nothing to do with the code you list, where is the WebElement code as it may be in there that there is some form of exception cast that is failing, Exception is a checked exception whilst stack overflow is a runtime exception

Comment: Which line you getting this exception exactly? Do you have a recursion in your code whether intentional or otherwise happening? Do you get the same when you make the method in class A inline into the class B?

Comment: Instead of driver.findElements when I am using driver.findElement the code is working fine for the same xpath. But using driver.findElement  is not the solution for me as there are many such elements on the page and I have to Click each element.     Below is the site i am trying to automate. https://demos.lightstreamer.com/AuthDemo/ I am logging in with user1/ wow and trying to click on each item in the list to subscribe

Comment: can you just add some print statement in the getitemList and check how many elements are returned?

Comment: @AkashChavan What is the xpath you are using for findElements?

Comment: I am using xpath ".//*[@id='hc6|stocks|item1']/span[2]"  just to make sure it is returning at least one element, actual xpath i want to use in code is ".//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]" which can give me all the elements on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not in the code. Issues was in the framework.

In frame work we have a class for driver where findElements method was not properly implemented, where as findElement method was properly implemented. Hence the issue was coming up only for the driver.findElements method and driver.findElement method was working fine.

Thanks all for the Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the XPATH as follows:

```
List<WebElement> itemList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]"));  // .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]
    System.out.println("list " + itemList);
```

returned the following elements:

```
list [[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]], [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a92615f2a2338af92c3dc57ff2366bf8)] -> xpath: .//*[@class='itemrow button']/span[2]]]
```

I hope it is not something problem with the XPATH or findElements method. Are you using any framework for writing tests?

In the line:

```
 //itemList = (driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hc6|stocks|item1']/span[2]"")));
```

observed additional double quotes present at the end of xpath `span[2]""`. check if it is the reason for the error.

java.lang.StackOverflowError occurs in case of recursive calls made. please look into your code whether recursion is happening.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.StackOverflowError cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.Exception

In the catch block, you used `Exception`, but code throws the `StackOverflowError` which is an Error (but not an Exception)

Go through the code thoroughly to find out where the recursion is happening.

Comment: check the double quotes. It may be causing the issue

Comment: I tried with the given ".//*[@id='hc6|stocks|item1']/span[2]" using findElements. it is matching only one element and not throwing any error

Comment: additional double quote was the typo while pasting the code, its not working even after removing the quote

Comment: updated the answer. with the XPATH, I am getting all the elements as expected without any error. try above line and let me know